# Passing data in a #selector function

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, mapkit

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to pass data when a button is tapped. I also want to animate the button when it is tapped. The button is inside a custom callout view of a map annotation. I tried setting a class property `dogIDOfUpvoteTapped`, and using that to store the data so the called function can access it. Unfortunately things get complicated when I want to interact with the button itself.

How do I get a reference to the 'CustomAnnotation' object from the called function 'upvoteButtonTapped'? I omitted a bunch of irrelevant code, but here's what I'm working with:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return
    }

    let customAnnotation = view.annotation as! CustomAnnotation
    let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: nil, options: nil)
    let calloutView = views?[0] as! CustomCalloutView

    dogIDOfUpvoteTapped = customAnnotation.dogID

    calloutView.scoreLabel.text = text
    calloutView.creatorLabel.text = customAnnotation.creator
    calloutView.dogImageView.image = customAnnotation.picture
    calloutView.upvoteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(upvoteTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(calloutView)
}
```

Here's the function for upvoteTapped, though nothing I'm doing there is really relevant to the question.

```
@objc func upvoteTapped() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("dogs").child(dogIDOfUpvoteTapped)
    ref.child("upvotes").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
        var currentUpvotes = Int(snap.value as! String)!
        currentUpvotes += 1
        ref.child("upvotes").setValue(String(currentUpvotes))
    })

}
```

Comment: You can’t add any parameters to a button but you can add properties to your view controller, add the desired values to it and access them from your IBAction

Comment: @LeoDabus If you look above, you'll see that I'm currently doing this. How would I go about animating the button when I don't have a reference to it from the action?

Comment: Sorry but I can’t see any view controller instance properties in the code above.

Comment: I just needed to pass a sender parameter

Comment: `@objc func upvoteTapped(_ button: UIButton)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@leo-dabus had it right in that you need to use the variant of method with sender (button).

Additionally, attach a tag to that button to identify it in a set, NB it must be integer, and I would presume you are using or have access to either the integer Id or index in list of your database item (dogID).

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return
    }

    let customAnnotation = view.annotation as! CustomAnnotation
    let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: nil, options: nil)
    let calloutView = views?[0] as! CustomCalloutView

    dogIDOfUpvoteTapped = customAnnotation.dogID

    calloutView.scoreLabel.text = text
    calloutView.creatorLabel.text = customAnnotation.creator
    calloutView.dogImageView.image = customAnnotation.picture
    calloutView.upvoteButton.tag = dogIDOfUpvoteTapped
    calloutView.upvoteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(upvoteTapped:), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(calloutView)
}

@objc func upvoteTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("dogs").child(button.tag)
    ref.child("upvotes").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
        var currentUpvotes = Int(snap.value as! String)!
        currentUpvotes += 1
        ref.child("upvotes").setValue(String(currentUpvotes))
    })

}
```

Without seeing class of customAnnotation.dogID, I have assumed it is an integer, if its a string or other, you would need to use a primary key or index that is an int. It's fair guess the primary key is an int though.